# problem understanding toggleClass and jquery selector

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, html

This is my getLiveSearchUsers function in my JS file, i cant understand it, Can somebody help me please.
i cant understand selector[0] and what is toggleClass doing here?

```
$.post("includes/handlers/ajax_search.php", {query:value, userLoggedIn: user}, function(data) {

    if($(".search_results_footer_empty")[0]) {
        $(".search_results_footer_empty").toggleClass("search_results_footer");
        $(".search_results_footer_empty").toggleClass("search_results_footer_empty");
    }

    $('.search_results').html(data);
    $('.search_results_footer').html("<a href='search.php?q=" + value + "'>See All Results</a>");

    if(data == "") {
        $('.search_results_footer').html("");
        $('.search_results_footer').toggleClass("search_results_footer_empty");
        $('.search_results_footer').toggleClass("search_results_footer");
    }else {
console.log("data is not empty. data is '" + data + "'");
```

}

Below is the html part.

```
        <div class="search_results">
        </div>

        <div class="search_results_footer_empty">
        </div>
```

Comment: it will be helpful if you can tell what exactly you dont understand

Comment: actually i am doing a social site course on udemy. so the code above is for the search bar, when it receives data as input, its doing some toggilng of classes, i cant understand how is it doing that and if($(".search_results_footer_empty")[0]), what does it check?

Answer (score 1):

The **[.toggleClass](http://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/)** method basically removes or adds a class to an html element. In your instance, it is the element with the class of *.search_results_footer*.

Regarding the selector[0], I am assuming you are referencing:

> $(".search_results_footer_empty")[0]

This basically means that the object itself in an array, and the code itself is referencing the first element in the array.

Comment: in the first line its, adding and what in the second line? in $(".search_results_footer_empty").toggleClass("search_results_footer_empty");

Comment: @ShahrukhTramboo - In the second line, its either adding or removing (meaning of toggle) the class search_results_footer_empty to the DOM element with the class .search_results_footer_empty

Comment: as it is empty as there arent any changes made in that, so it removes then?

Comment: @ShahrukhTramboo - Are you referring to the element itself or the class name? From what I can infer from the code you have given, there is a div for when there are search results and a div for when there are no search results. Notice the if that finds out if the data variable is empty or not.

Comment: @ShahrukhTramboo - No worries. If my answer helped you, please mark it as such.

Comment: i marked it, but something with the less reputation , less than 15

Comment: @ShahrukhTramboo - Once you get enough reputation, be sure to mark it.

Answer (score 0):

When you select elements through the jQuery selector `$('.element')` you can then reference either all the jQuery elements that meet the selector and an array of HTML elements like you would access them by `document.querySelector('element')`.

The difference between accessing a jQuery element and an HTML element is that:

1. you cannot use jQuery functions on an HTML element
2. in order to access the HTML element from a jQuery selector you use `$('.element')[i]` with the `i` being the nth element of the HTML element array.

About the `toggleClass` function checkout tomerpacific's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53800855/7380613), or checkout the jQuery [docs](http://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/).